# I can't install any package related to PHP with yum

Tags: php, yum, centos7

I can't install any package related PHP, I get a yum error: `No package php available`.
My `PHP` version is 5.4.37 on Centos 7. I installed remi for other purposes and I think that the repository is not compatible with PHP version but I don't  know how to fix it.

```
[root@server ~]# sudo yum install php php-pear
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: centosmirror.netcup.net
 * remi: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * remi-safe: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * updates: centosmirror.netcup.net
No package php available.
No package php-pear available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: first, this is a SuperUser question; second, you don't need sudo when you're are logged as root; third, have you tried `yum search php`?

Comment: Look like a "panel" server, search "exclude" directive in yum.conf.

Comment: `yum search php ` prints normal result

Comment: "prints normal result" => please paste.

Comment: `[root@server ~]# yum search php
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * epel: mirrors.n-ix.net
 * extras: mirror.checkdomain.de
 * remi: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * remi-safe: mirror5.layerjet.com
 * updates: mirror.checkdomain.de
================================================ N/S matched: php =================================================
geos-php.x86_64 : PHP modules for GEOS
graphviz-php.x86_64 : PHP extension for graphviz
nntpgrab-php.x86_64 : PHP module which allows PHP scripts to 
 ... ` (No enough space for all result)

Comment: grep exclude /etc/yum.conf /etc/yum.repos.d/*repo

Comment: [root@server ~]# grep exclude /etc/yum.conf /etc/yum.repos.d/*repo
/etc/yum.conf:exclude=apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* mariadb* da_* *ftp* exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot*  (Not any thing happend)

Answer (score 9):

You have, in yum configuration:

```
exclude=apache* httpd* mod_* mysql* MySQL* mariadb* da_* ftp exim* sendmail* php* bind-chroot*
```

This is very probably a "panel" enabled server (cpanel or others), which provides its own PHP stack.

So by design, you cannot install "php*" packages from standard repository or any other 3rd party repository. Such distribution is so altered, that it is often considered as "Not CentOS".

So, better to ask your php stack provider for how to update it (if possible, without breaking the panel application)

Comment: You can use the following command to find which package provides your current PHP version : rpm -qf $(which php)

Comment: [root@server ~]# rpm -qf $(which php)
file /usr/local/bin/php is not owned by any package

Comment: So... seems to be a "build from sources"  php... What says "rpm -qa '*php*' "

Comment: [root@server ~]# rpm -qa 'php'
[root@server ~]# rpm -qf $(which php)
file /usr/local/bin/php is not owned by any package

Comment: [root@server /]# rpm -qa '*php*'
[root@server /]# rpm -qf $(which php)
file /usr/local/bin/php is not owned by any package

Comment: So you only have a "build from source" version of PHP. You can clean the exclude line in yum.conf, and install the version you want to avoid having to build it.

Comment: which php or yum should I reinstall after cleaning the exclude line in yum.conf?

Comment: once yum fixed, you can use the initially posted command (with "remi" enabled, you will get latest PHP 5.4.45, but as PHP 5.4 is now EOL, you should consider to enable "remi-php55" or "remi-php56")

Answer (score 5):

As suggested in other answer, this may be related to excludes set in yum.conf
The command below allows to run the installation of excluded packages without modifying the conf file:

```
yum --disableexcludes=main install php
```

**BUT**

It seems like it might be better to re-install PHP by the means of the control panel installed. IE Cpanel - EasyApache..

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: Ok, I added a few words.