# Installing php-ldap on CentOs

Tags: php, linux, ldap, centos6

I have an unmanaged VPS server preinstalled with CentOs 6.6 and WHM/CPanel.  I am trying to install php-ldap but it just says package not found.  I have not been able to find anywhere what repository it should be in.  How can I install ldap on my server to work with php 5.4?  I am trying to manage Windows Server 2012 R2 Active Directory.

```
root@vps [~]# yum install php-ldap
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.5ninesolutions.com
 * epel: fedora-epel.mirror.lstn.net
 * extras: centos.arvixe.com
 * updates: pubmirrors.dal.corespace.com
No package php-ldap available.
Error: Nothing to do
root@vps [~]#
```

Comment: Not a CentOS expert by any means, but http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php-ldap lists packages for 6.7. Would those be compatible with 6.6? Also check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52666/how-do-i-install-the-stock-centos-repositories in case you don't have the default repositories added.

Comment: I ended up switching to Ubuntu server as I know it much better. Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a cpanel serveur you probably have an "exclude" line in yum.conf (see [I can't install any package related to PHP with yum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32546527)) which prevent you to install/upgrade php from another repository.

To see the provider of "php", user this command

```
rpm -qf $(which php)
```

And the ldap extension, if available will be in the same namespace.

Notice switch the php stack from the cpanel provider to another repo can break it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that the base repos typically don't contain boutique builds for PHP. Your best bet is to install a different repo, like the [Remi repo](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en), which [does contain that RPM](http://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/6/remi/x86_64/repoview/php-ldap.html).

While I'm at it, PHP 5.4 went [End-of-life 4 days ago](http://php.net/supported-versions.php). Remi offers 5.5 and 5.6 so you should consider upgrading

Comment: "End of Life" by the OEM is not the same as "Unsupported", since the distro is an enterprise distro with historically a decade of support (all bets are off now they're with HAL, though).

Answer (score 0):

Get the php version you are running by

```
php -v
```

if not worked try

```
rpm -qa |grep php
```

if the php version is 5.4 then use

```
sudo yum install php54w-ldap
```

if 5.6

```
sudo yum install php56w-ldap
```

and so on.